# How can I get a list of software installed via the Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, app-store

I'd like to programmatically get a list of all the software on my Mac that was installed via the Mac App Store.  I'm sure that this list must exist somewhere on my computer, but I can't figure out where it would be. I couldn't find any documented way to get this list, but I'd be happy with an undocumented way. It would be fine to read files or call functions. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a list does not likely exist on the user's system. If you try to view the purchases tab of the App Store without internet, you won't see anything. This is likely because the App Store just downloads a list of the user's purchases and checks to see which ones exist on the current system but doesn't save this data anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, the additional investigation that I did seemed to indicate that it pulls down a list of packages that you have purchased from the App store, and then separately asks the store for a list of updates to those packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the App Store in your dock, when it opens there is a tab labeled 'purchases'. I think that should give you what you're looking for.

EDIT: If the particular software is installed on your machine, it says 'installed' next to the purchase, in case you've got your account tied to more than one machine this is helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I wanted to get the list programmatically.